Pallet assets `TokenError` in stead of native error
When I mint an asset that not exist in pallet assets I receive the DispatchError::Token(UnknownAsset) error instead of pallet assets' native Unknown error. Is this expected behaviour? If so, shouldn't there be a conversion to Unknown?

Not, 100% sure if this is expected. However, the code is written this way. This into_result() is the "problem". It converts from the DepositConsequence to a Result<(), TokenError> and thus it returns the DispatchError::Token(Unknown).
If you want to fix this, please open a pull request.
